# SQL5193N The current session user does not have usage privilege on any enabled workloads

Tags: db2, sql-grant, db2-luw

I'm getting the error while querying DB2 database 'SQL5193N  The current session user does not have usage privilege on any enabled workloads'

How should I check if a user has usage permission on workloads?

Answer (score 1):

To granting the USAGE privilege on a workload. You can use;
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/t0051489.html

To check whether the user has DBADM authority:

```
db2 "SELECT DISTINCT GRANTEETYPE, GRANTEE, DBADMAUTH from SYSCAT.DBAUTH"
```

To grant the DBADM authority to the user using the following command:

```
db2 "GRANT DBADM ON DATABASE TO USER <USERID>"
```

Comment: It seems user has DBADM auth but still I'm getting the same error. For user DB2ADMIN , column DBADMAUTH is 'Y'.