# Correct method of granting limited access to user in DB2?

Tags: permissions, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to grant data access rights to a DB/2 database and its tables to a user. I have DB/2 10.5 installed on a CentOS 7 server.

I created a database, schema & table:

```
create database mydb1
connect to mydb1
create schema myschema
create table myschema.mytab1 (empid int, empname varchar(50))
grant connect, dataaccess on database on database to user osuser2
grant select,insert,update,delete on myschema.mytab1 to user osuser2
```

When I login as OS user: osuser2 and give the command: `db2 select * from myschema.tab1`, I get the error:
`SQL5193N  The current session user does not have usage privilege on any enabled workloads.  SQLSTATE=425`

What am I doing wrong?

This error is given in many questions such as [SQL5193N The current session user does not have usage privilege on any enabled workloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703712/sql5193n-the-current-session-user-does-not-have-usage-privilege-on-any-enabled-w)

This error goes away and everything works if I use the command:

```
grant dbadm on database to user osuser2
```

Of course, by doing that, the user gets administrative rights can can create / drop tables.

Comment: If what you've shown is the actual, complete set of commands you issue the error you quote is not possible. Do you in fact create a restrictive database?

Comment: @mustaccio You are completely correct. It was a restrictive database. I dropped  and recreated and all better now. I had thought that non-restrictive means r/w authorities are given to PUBLIC by default so had used that keyword. Thanks, man.

Comment: @mustaccio Oh! Made a booboo there.  I've deleted my answer so you can post your answer which I would then mark as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

we resolved this by adding this grant statement:

```
GRANT USAGE ON WORKLOAD SYSDEFAULTUSERWORKLOAD TO GROUP <groupname>;
```

you can also use user:

```
GRANT USAGE ON WORKLOAD SYSDEFAULTUSERWORKLOAD TO USER <username>;
```